# Mas de un left join o inner join a una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, join

Tengo la siguiente consulta que con la función `where` funciona bastante bien, sin embargo al ser por `where` me omite algunas lineas, por lo que necesitaría usar un `left join`... Pero no logro que me muestre la información correctamente, me podrían ayudar con la sintaxis de mi consulta.

Explicación tablas

SLI_nuevo: me muestra lo datos de una Id_oc que me llegara a la sucursal
Recepción_contenedores_odbms: me muestra lo que a recibido cada sucursal, por producto (sku), unidades, cantidad e ID_contenedor.

En definitiva necesito unir ambas para saber cuanto recibió cada sucursal por "ID_OC" con el respectivo detalle.

Estructura Tabla SLI_nuevo:

```
Id_oc    id_contenedor     sku     cantidad
8332582  TCLU4722057      3230457   500
8332582  TCLU4722057      3230465   675
8332582  TCLU4722057      3230473   700
8332582  TCLU4722057      3230481   725
8332582  TCLU4722057      3230503   850
8332582  TCLU4722057      3230511   800
8332582  TCLU4722057      323052X   475
```

Estructura tabla Recepcion_contenedores_odbms

```
Id_oc   id_contenedor   sku     cantidad_recibida_sku
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230457          500
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230465          675
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230473          450
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230481          575
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230503          750
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230511          700
```

**Lo que deseo obtener** (El campo en null es el que no me muestra ocupando `where`) hay que considerar que la columna id_contenedor, sku e id_oc son únicas por proceso de recepción de la sucursal por eso debo igualarlas:

```
Id_oc  | id_contenedor|  sku    |cantidad|  |cantidad_recibida_sku  |   DIF  |
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230457    500                  500               0
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230465    675                  675               0
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230473    700                  450              250
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230481    725                  575              150
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230503    850                  750              100
8332582 TCLU4722057    3230511    800                  700              100
8332582 TCLU4722057    323052X    475                  null             475
```

Consulta 1 con `where` :

```
Select SLI_nuevo.id_oc, SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor, SLI_nuevo.sku, 
SLI_nuevo.cantidad, recepcion_contenedores_odbms.cantidad_recibida_sku,
SLI_nuevo.cantidad-recepcion_contenedores_odbms.cantidad_recibida_sku as DIF, 
recepcion_contenedores_odbms.fecha_recepcion
From SLI_nuevo, recepcion_contenedores_odbms
where SLI_nuevo.id_oc=recepcion_contenedores_odbms.id_oc
and SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor=recepcion_contenedores_odbms.id_contenedor
and SLI_nuevo.sku=recepcion_contenedores_odbms.sku
and SLI_nuevo.id_oc in ('8332582');
```

Query 2 ocupando `left` (el problema es que me repite los datos hacia bajo casi millones por lo que creo que debe haber un error en la sintaxis que ocupo).

```
Select SLI_nuevo.id_oc, SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor, SLI_nuevo.sku, 
SLI_nuevo.cantidad, r1.cantidad_recibida_sku,
SLI_nuevo.cantidad-r1.cantidad_recibida_sku as DIF, r3.fecha_recepcion
From recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r1 left join SLI_nuevo on r1.id_oc = SLI_nuevo.id_oc
left join recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r2 on r2.id_contenedor=SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor
left join recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r3 on r3.sku = SLI_nuevo.sku
where  SLI_nuevo.id_oc in ('8332582')
```

Comment: Y que es lo que deberia mostrar? y como es el aspecto de tus tablas? trata de editar tu pregunto y agregar estos detalles para poder ayudarte saludos

Comment: No puedes hacer `id_contenedor = id_contenedor OR  sku = sku` y hacer un solo left? (omití los aliases)

Comment: Si lo hago de esta manera, me omitirá los datos que no coinciden y quiero que me muestre todo, detallare la estructura de la tabla y lo que deseo obtener para mayor claridad

Comment: @EdgarVazquez hice algunas ediciones, espero que se entienda y me puedan ayudar, Gracias !!

Comment: se me hace muy confuso seguir con todos los nombre.. pero estan mal tus joins. Las tablas se conectan por un solo campo o por 3?

Comment: @gbianchi para este caso particular debe considerar conectarse en base a lo 3 campos, por que los 3 son unicos para cada proceso. Una "ID_OC" puede tener varios "ID_contenedor" y "SKU", por lo cual la segunda tabla la "recepcion_contenedores_odbms", es la que me muestra lo que a llegado de la otra tabla "SLI_nuevo".

Comment: entonces, lo primero era poner los 3 campos como condicion de join.. si pones uno solo, se va a conectar solo por ese.

Comment: @gbianchi por ahí va mi duda como hacer 3 join para una misma tabla, por que de la manera que lo estoy haciendo me esta duplicando la información... por lo que algo estoy haciendo mal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si desarmamos tu select, vemos el siguiente problema:

```
Select SLI_nuevo.id_oc, SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor, SLI_nuevo.sku, 
SLI_nuevo.cantidad, r1.cantidad_recibida_sku,
SLI_nuevo.cantidad-r1.cantidad_recibida_sku as DIF, r3.fecha_recepcion
From 
    recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r1 left join SLI_nuevo on r1.id_oc = SLI_nuevo.id_oc
    left join recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r2 on r2.id_contenedor=SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor
    left join recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r3 on r3.sku = SLI_nuevo.sku
where  SLI_nuevo.id_oc in ('8332582')
```

La tabla recepcion contenedores esta 3 veces, porque en lugar de hacer un solo join con 3 condiciones, trataste de unir la tabla 3 veces.

La parte interna del join, la clausula ON, funciona como un where aplicado a la condición de join. Por lo tanto admite todas (o casi, dependiendo de la base de datos) las opciones que podes poner en un where.

Por lo tanto, tu from es mucho mas simple de lo que vos pensas, y ahi se soluciona tu problema

```
From 
    recepcion_contenedores_odbms as r1 
        left join SLI_nuevo 
            on r1.id_oc = SLI_nuevo.id_oc 
            and r1.id_contenedor=SLI_nuevo.id_contenedor 
            and r1.sku = SLI_nuevo.sku
```

(lo idente asi a proposito para que se entendiera)

Comment: Funciono perfecto, muchas gracias por el apoyo...tal como indicas era bastante mas simple... quedo ok !

Comment: aprovecha y lee el [tour] para entender como funcionamos.. Recuerda agregarte un nombre de usuario para que podamos reconocerte en el futuro!!!!